# Loop interaction with other loop

Tags: c, loops, interaction

I'm trying to create a program that when it gets a certain value in the loop, it would broadcast some sort of signal to another main loop and it will start doing whatever it needs to do. I have searched online about multiple loops interacting with each other, but I found nothing. 
**For example:** I ask the user for a number. When I receive the number, it will check what number it got and send a signal to the proper loop and the calculation there. When it's done, it sends the signal back to the main loop and repeats the whole process again until the user inputs a specific number to terminate the program. **P.S Can you explain it in a simple way if possible, I am new(ish) to C.**

**Edit: Code**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int ier, cand, product, check, i = 1;

  printf("Input only whole numbers!");
  printf("\nMultiplier: ");
  scanf("%d", &ier);
  printf("\nMultiplicand: ");
  scanf("%d", &cand);

  while(i != 0){
    if((ier == 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand == 0)){
      printf("Product: 0")
      printf("Input only whole numbers!");
      printf("\nMultiplier: ");
      scanf("%d", &ier);
      printf("\nMultiplicand: ");
      scanf("%d", &cand);
    }
    if((ier > 0 && cand > 0) || (ier < 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand < 0))
  }

  while(i != 0){
    if((ier < 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand < 0)){
      printf("Values must not be negative");
      printf("Input only whole numbers!");
      printf("\nMultiplier: ");
      scanf("%d", &ier);
      printf("\nMultiplicand: ");
      scanf("%d", &cand);
    }
    if(ier > 0 && cand > 0){
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: These aren't independent loops the way you describe it. Sounds like you just want to have one loop that calls a function that does a calculation, unless that calculation takes so long that you want to be able to get more from the user before it finishes. If that's the case, you need to choose a language that supports multiple threads, or use the operating system to create tasks and use pipes or messages. Your question doesn't have any specific context to narrow it down much further than that.

Comment: I wrote a code with if statement to make it work but it got too complicated. I will still add it.

Comment: Sounds like you could solve this with nested loops.  Inner loop repeats until it has valid data, then breaks out so the outer loop can utilize the data.

Comment: Isn't a nested loop a loop in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By starting on c, I assume you are keeping it single-threaded (only one process executing your program). Going multi-thread is a different story and it's really complex.

In this case, you have to think of a c program not as a group of loops that interact with each other, but a single batch of instructions that get executed in order, one after the other.

A "Loop" is just that when you finish a set instruction, you jump back to some instructions before and repeat the same instructions. Same as when a "If" let's you skip some instructions.

So in your case you can nest Loops to do what you want, something like:

```
Start program
finished = false
Start loop while not finished
    Ask user for a number x
    If x < 0 Then finished = true
    i = 0
    Start loop while i < x
        Print i
        i = i + 1
    End loop
End loop
End program
```

This is called "pseudocode", it's just a code so you can better understand how things go without having to understand a specific code syntaxis.
This program will ask a user for a number in a loop, until the user enters a negative number, and then print out all the numbers from 0 up to the one the user entered.